# how to install pyrouge completely?

Tags: python

I have installed **pyrouge** using: `pip install pyrouge`,

and cmd: `C://python27/scripts/pip install pyrouge`.

But it wasn't enough. I've found that I should use another: `pyrough_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory` then.

I don't know how to use it and where (whether in `C://python27/scripts/` or elsewhere) and instead of `/absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory`, what should I write.

Can anyone help me?
thanks
yes, I'm the admin.  the error was:

```
>>> from pyrouge import Rouge155

>>> r = Rouge155()

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>

r = Rouge155()

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 88, in        
__init__
self.__set_rouge_dir(rouge_dir)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 402, in _   
_set_rouge_dir
self._home_dir = self.__get_rouge_home_dir_from_settings()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyrouge\Rouge155.py", line 418, in 
__get_rouge_home_dir_from_settings
config.read_file(f)
File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 691, in read_file
self._read(f, source)
File "C:\Python34\lib\configparser.py", line 1058, in _read
raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'C:\\Users\\sara\\AppData\\Roaming\\pyrouge\\settings.ini', line: 5
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
```

I've found "pyrough_set_rouge_path /absolute/path/to/ROUGE-1.5.5/directory" at:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrouge/0.1.0

Comment: Where have you found this/why do you think this is needed?

Comment: Can you post the error? did you run as administrator? In windows, open the **cmd as administrator** let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin Heinzerling helped me, and his solution works. Instead of 
r = Rouge155()
 use
r = Rouge155('C://RELEASE-1.5.5')
and C://RELEASE-1.5.5 is the ROUGE-1.5.5 path,  mine is C://RELEASE-1.5.5

Answer (score 0):

unbound method output_to_dict() must be called with Rouge155 instance as first argument (got instancemethod instance instead)